# Image cannot be converter from byte array and display in picture box

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2

I am creating a windows application using Visual Studio 2010. Using SQL Server 2008 R2 as database and save image as datatype `image`. Uploading is successfully done. But I got the error **Parameter invalid** while retrieving the image from database and displaying it in a `PictureBox`.

This is my code

```
 byte[] pic = ((byte[])dr["image1"]);
    Image newImage;

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(pic, 0, Convert.ToInt32(pic.Length))) 
    {
        ms.Write(pic, 0, pic.Length);

        //Set image variable value using memory stream.
        newImage = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
    }

    //set picture
    pictureBox1.Image = newImage;
```

Comment: `image` data type will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this data type in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the image is not being correctly saved to the database. Can you post the code that you are using?

Comment: if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
                    {

                        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                        pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, pictureBox1.Image.RawFormat);
                        byte[] bimage = ms.GetBuffer();
                        ms.Close();
                        string ins = "insert into registration(image1,path) values ('" + bimage + "','" + t + "')";
                       
                        obj.Exe_NonQuery(ins);
                        
                        MessageBox.Show("Saved Successfully");
                   }

Comment: I try this code also **
 if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
                    {

                        ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
                        byte[] bimage = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(pictureBox1.Image, typeof(byte[]));
                        string ins = "insert into registration(image1,path) values ('" + bimage + "','" + t + "')";
                        obj.Exe_NonQuery(ins);
                        MessageBox.Show("Saved Successfully");
                   }**

Comment: You need to use parameters to insert values of type byte[]. Also, use ms.ToArray() instead of ms.GetBuffer().

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a memory stream that contains the image data, but then you write the image data to the stream again. Just create the memory stream and use it:

```
byte[] pic = (byte[])dr["image1"];
Image newImage;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(pic)) {
  //Set image variable value using memory stream.
  newImage = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
}
//set picture
pictureBox1.Image = newImage;
```